# Copy the design of the Docs review queue for the other queues

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues, design

Currently, the Docs review queue has a nice table showing how the review played out:

[image: colorful!]

However, other review queues do not have this design:

[image: :(]

Can they be upgraded to look like the Docs one?

Comment: The ability to add comments as needed would be beneficial.

Comment: Hmm.. This is indeed feature.

Answer (score 19):

I totally agree with this. Even the buttons for the Docs review queue have a clearer and a more visually appealing design, compared to those in the other queues.

---

#### Docs review queue

> [image: Docs]

#### Other queues

> [image: QA]

Comment: *"a clearer and a more visually appealing design"* Only for users who are not red/green color-blind. Also, while I agree with the agreement with this request (heh), I don't like the idea of losing the "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" buttons, so I'd actually rather keep the buttons from the current review queues as we have them. Changing the colors would be fine, though. It doesn't make it any worse for a colorblind user.

Comment: Regarding color-blindness: in the case above the buttons have not only different color, but a different brightness *because* of different color - you can try it out yourself in colorblindness simulator)

Comment: @IgorB Serious question, does it really make it more difficult for color blind people to use? If it is at the very least not harmful, is there any reason to not change the color? The words will still be there.

Comment: I'd suggest that the 'skip' button should be orange (or another colour other than white), because we all know that people don't skip reviews often enough when they don't know what to do.

Comment: @SandPiper nope - even the people with monochromatic vision would profit of this change. if you interested in subject you may like to check following discussion on UX SE [Alert colors are really user-friendly to color-blind users?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98973/alert-colors-are-really-user-friendly-to-color-blind-users/99409)